# Migration from JBoss EAP 6.4 to JBoss EAP 7.1 failed

Tags: jboss, migration, jboss-eap-6, jboss-eap-7

I try to migrate my JBoss EAP 6.4 to JBoss EAP 7.1 using the JBoss migration tool.
When I run the following command:

```
jboss-eap-7.1/bin $ ./jboss-server-migration.sh --source /Path/to/the/old/jboss-eap-6.4
```

I get the following error (myjboss.xml is my configuration file in eap-6.4):

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Task Summary
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 server .......................................................................................... FAIL
  standalone ..................................................................................... FAIL
   contents.standalone.migrate-content-dir ....................................................... SUCCESS
    contents.standalone.migrate-content(path=23/1abe29b3aac471aed9b392c6cfe1ec457eea53/content) .. SUCCESS
   standalone-configurations ..................................................................... FAIL
    standalone-configuration(source=myjboss.xml) ..................................................... FAIL

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Migration Result: FAIL
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Stacktrace:

```
ERROR [logger] Migration failed: org.jboss.migration.core.ServerMigrationFailureException: org.jboss.migration.wfly10.config.management.ManagementOperationException: org.wildfly.core.embedded.EmbeddedProcessStartException: WFLYEMB0021: Cannot start embedded process
        at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskExecutionImpl.run(TaskExecutionImpl.java:174) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskExecutionImpl.execute(TaskExecutionImpl.java:159) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskContextImpl.execute(TaskContextImpl.java:68) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskContextImpl.execute(TaskContextImpl.java:32) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.wfly10.config.task.ServerConfigurationsMigration$Task$1.onYes(ServerConfigurationsMigration.java:139) [jboss-server-migration-wildfly10.0-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.console.UserConfirmation.execute(UserConfirmation.java:76) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.wfly10.config.task.ServerConfigurationsMigration$Task.confirmConfig(ServerConfigurationsMigration.java:148) [jboss-server-migration-wildfly10.0-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.wfly10.config.task.ServerConfigurationsMigration$Task.confirmAllConfigs(ServerConfigurationsMigration.java:128) [jboss-server-migration-wildfly10.0-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.wfly10.config.task.ServerConfigurationsMigration$Task.run(ServerConfigurationsMigration.java:104) [jboss-server-migration-wildfly10.0-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskExecutionImpl.run(TaskExecutionImpl.java:169) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskExecutionImpl.execute(TaskExecutionImpl.java:159) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskContextImpl.execute(TaskContextImpl.java:68) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskContextImpl.execute(TaskContextImpl.java:32) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.wfly10.config.task.StandaloneServerMigration$1.run(StandaloneServerMigration.java:60) [jboss-server-migration-wildfly10.0-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.console.UserConfirmationServerMigrationTask.runTask(UserConfirmationServerMigrationTask.java:58) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.console.UserConfirmationServerMigrationTask.confirmTaskRun(UserConfirmationServerMigrationTask.java:50) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.console.UserConfirmationServerMigrationTask.run(UserConfirmationServerMigrationTask.java:63) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.env.SkippableByEnvServerMigrationTask.run(SkippableByEnvServerMigrationTask.java:47) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskExecutionImpl.run(TaskExecutionImpl.java:169) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskExecutionImpl.execute(TaskExecutionImpl.java:159) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskContextImpl.execute(TaskContextImpl.java:68) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskContextImpl.execute(TaskContextImpl.java:32) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.wfly10.config.task.ServerMigration.run(ServerMigration.java:45) [jboss-server-migration-wildfly10.0-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.wfly10.WildFlyServer10.migrate(WildFlyServer10.java:47) [jboss-server-migration-wildfly10.0-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.ServerMigration$1.run(ServerMigration.java:153) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskExecutionImpl.run(TaskExecutionImpl.java:169) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.ServerMigration.run(ServerMigration.java:160) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.migration.cli.CommandLineServerMigration.main(CommandLineServerMigration.java:115) [jboss-server-migration-cli-1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.0.7.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:345) [jboss-modules.jar:1.6.5.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:525) [jboss-modules.jar:1.6.5.Final-redhat-00001]
```

any Ideas?

Thanks 
Eldon

Comment: I have the same issue, how you fix it

Comment: Our solution: We switched to SpringBoot.
Nice side effect: We don't have any JBoss license costs anymore

Answer (score 0):

might be a bad configuration file, get specific error information from EAP_HOME/migration/logs file